# Where should I ask this question? Work tools and work managment tools for a volunteer activism group?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, asking-questions

We have about 15 people with more joining in. We'll have our overview group & several subprojects.

We need tools to coordinate ourselves. **Where do I ask about tool ideas?**

I've looked around and PM and alternatives to Basecamp seem to cost per user. We can afford to pay a flat year fee but that's all.

Need:
Chatting at top level, that shows up in member's email and stays on the tool.
Chatting for each project, separate from the top level.
Ideally, subtopic conversations within each project.
File storage or area to put links to google docs & spreadsheets.
List of members
Search ability to search emails, search for a member's info.

Pleasant, pretty easy to use interface. Most members aren't overly tech sophisticated.

I've looked through the stack applications and found project management, but it was about how to, not tools to. I've looked through meta questions, but haven't seen any the seem related.

Comment: I do not understand the down votes. No one's commented on what would be improvable. I spent several hours and came back to search some more, before thinking to ask in meta, since I was obviously clueless on where I should go. What more is needed? I'm obviously new, and downvotes were done immediately.

Answer (score -1):

Ask on [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=project+management) using a search term such as "project management".

You can also try on the main [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=project+management) site; while producing a lot of results it gives a number of different sites where one can see questions similar to your own.

Comment: Would Web Applications be a better fit than [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: Web Applications doesn't allow recommendation questions.

Comment: As for Mast's comment the OP doesn't indicate in their question, nor from their SO profile, that they'd be capable of hosting; and that addresses N8te's observation, that they need to [use an existing framework](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4569/is-your-question-about-using-web-applications), because otherwise the ***wrong*** [advice would be Webmasters.SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project-management) (featuring nothing under that Tag). The OP's ability to admin isn't parallel with their ability to compile and host the APP, and where ...

Comment: As one can see this question is a [cross site duplicate](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7547/what-options-are-available-for-collaborative-task-management) (a reason we can't use to close this question); since they have their answer (from either of the links I offered in my answer) it's a matter of asking how does one use **X** to do **Y**.

Comment: That link to Software Recommendations worked. I didn't even have to ask a question. Some searching finally turned out a few relevant questions.

Comment: I had tried the stockexchange.com before posting the queston. I didn't know what it was called. Just looked like a place to find stack sites, and found project management there. So that was a good idea. Now I know the name for next time.